Not table able to load html page with table using post method - https://cestat.gov.in/casestatus
I want to get the data shown in HTML table in this website. Python requests and beautifulsoup are the main packages used. When I use post method with the parameters I get the HTML page with empty table. I'm not table to understand what is going on. 
def casestatus_name(csrf, party):

    try:
       test = url_get('https://cestat.gov.in')
       cookies = test.cookies.get_dict()
       test.raise_for_status()
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      sys.exit(1)

    payload = {
    'csrf_token': cookies['csrf_cookie_name'],
    'schema_type': 'bangalore',
    'app_type': 'pno',
    'token_no': party,
    'captcha_code': '111111',
    'button3': 'SEARCH'
    }

   response = requests.post("https://cestat.gov.in/casestatus", json=payload)

   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
   table = soup.find_all('table', id='example')
   print(response.text)
   return response


the site is painfully slow...

the data seems easy to access, but you need to use requests.session

tried session    s = requests.Session()                                                                          response = s.get('https://cestat.gov.in/casestatus', headers = payload)   But still the same result. Please help @folengateis

here's a working example with session
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://cestat.gov.in/casestatus"
party = "access enterprises"
with requests.session() as s:
    # one first GET to retrieve the csrf token and other cookies
    s.get(url)
    payload = {
        'csrf_token': s.cookies['csrf_cookie_name'],
        'schema_type': 'bangalore',
        'app_type': 'pno',
        'token_no': party,
        'captcha_code': '111111',
        'button3': 'SEARCH'
    }

    response = s.post(url, data=payload)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    link = soup.select_one('table#example a')['href']
    print(link)

    # if you want to scrape this link, just stay within the session
    # response2 = s.get(link)

output:
https://cestat.gov.in/casedetailreport/2952510201062016/bangalore


Great! This solved my problem. Thank you
